# If we aren't interested in interpretation of control variables in a regression model, is spurious correlation still problematic

Tags: multiple-regression, modeling, feature-selection, model

If I were estimating the treatment effect in a linear regression model. Assuming there isn't a risk of collider bias and multicollinearity, would it be acceptable to add in as many covariates as possible to control for the remaining variation unexplained by the treatment effect variable? Or would the risk of including variables that are spuriously correlated invalidate any inference made on the adjusted treatment effect variable?

Also, in a non-linear model, because of non-collapsibility, is it in fact preferred to do this to control for all unexplained variation that biases the treatment effect variable from the lack of an error term?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: About non-collapsibility: let's talk, for example, about odds ratios. In that case, the list of variables you include in the regression not only allows you to control for a source of bias, but the parameter you're going to estimate changes, switching from a marginal to a conditional odds ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Each variable you include costs you a degree of freedom, which makes your tests less powerful and standard errors wider, and the whole fit less stable, partially as you mentioned, because of spurious correlations, but also simply because you are just fitting more stuff.